# How to get Url params after slash

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a URL "https://www.example.com/username" and I want to extract the username from the URL. For example 'https://www.facebook.com/david'

Comment: Is the username always the path component of the url?

Comment: [`window.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname)

Comment: how is `https://www.facebook.com/david` extracted from `https://www.example.com/username`?

Comment: This should have been very easy to research enough yourself to at least come up with a starting point . [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I just wan to get the parameter from the URLs stated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 let href = "https://www.facebook.com/david"; 
// let href = "https://www.facebook.com/david"; // Current window url; 

// Creating URL object
let url = new URL(href);

console.log(url.pathname.substring(1));  // David

// If you looking for parameters after ? 
let exampleUrl = "https://www.facebook.com?name=david";
let paramUrl = new URL(exampleUrl);

console.log(paramUrl.searchParams.get("name"));   // david or null if not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

In node.js, you should use the [url module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_pathname).

```
const Url = require('url');
console.log(new Url('https://www.facebook.com/david').pathname);
// 'david'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**URL API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and if you want to get rid of leading `/` you can use [**substring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) after taking the [**pathname**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) from url

```js
let url = `https://www.example.com/username`
let url2 = `https://www.example.com/username/somevalue`

let parsed = (url)=> {
   let urlParsed = new URL(url)
   return urlParsed.pathname.substring(1)
}

console.log(parsed(url))
console.log(parsed(url2))
```